# Subtract values from 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables as follows

Forecasted

```
Account,Date,Type,Hours

123456,11/2/2013,REG,40
123456,11/9/2013,REG,32
```

Worked

```
Account,Date,Type,Hours

123456, 11/2/2013,REG,8
123456, 11/2/2013,REG,10
123456, 11/2/2013,REG,10
123456, 11/2/2013,REG,10
123456, 11/9/2013,VAC,8
123456, 11/9/2013,REG,8
123456, 11/9/2013,REG,8
123456, 11/9/2013,REG,8
```

I need the following output

```
123456
11/2/2013
REG 40 - 38 = 2
11/9/2013
REG 32 - 24 = 8
Vac 0 - 8 = -8
```

I basically need the difference between the forcasted table and worked table. The user will enter a date (11/9/2013) and the results will include that date and 7 days prior so in this example it would include 11/9/2013 and 11/2/2013. I also only want employees that are found in the forecasted table

Comment: I tried using a union to do it but that didn't work. Part of my query does use a union to return the forecasted hours and then the worked hours. That works fine it is the difference between the 2 where I get stuck

Comment: Edit your question to show the union query you tried and the results you got.  That might stave off those who want to close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query. It uses full outer join as the data may be different in 2 tables (the types may be different):

```
declare @date date = '11/9/2013'

select f.Account, f.[Date],
case when f.[Type] is not null then f.[Type] else w.[Type] end [Type],
ISNULL(f.Hours, 0) - ISNULL(w.Hours, 0) Hours
from
    (select Account, [Date], [Type], SUM(Hours) Hours
    from Forecasted
    where [Date] >= dateadd(dd, -7, @date) and [Date] <= @date
    group by Account, [Date], [Type]) f
full outer join
    (select Account, [Date], [Type], SUM(Hours) Hours
    from Worked
    where [Date] >= dateadd(dd, -7, @date) and [Date] <= @date
    group by Account, [Date], [Type]) w
on f.Account = w.Account and f.[Date] = w.[Date] and f.[Type] = w.[Type]
```

Answer (score 1):

This first part should probably be a comment, but I don't have enough reputation to comment yet.

So in the worked table the date is the same for 4 days, so is the date representative of the work week? And it looks like you need to sum the hours for each entry for the given date in worked then compare it to the forcasted, yes?

Assuming this is the case, you first need an input from the user in a defined date form. Then:

```
Select f.Hours + ' - ' + SUM(select hours from Worked where date=USER_INPUT) + ' = ' + f.hours-w.hours
from forcasted f
outer join  worked w
on f.account = w.account
where f.date=USER_INPUT
```

This is obviously pseudocode of sorts but hopefully this will give you an idea of how to approach this.

Comment: upvoted for the remarks about comments and reputation.

Comment: Appreciate it, thanks.